# call javascript function on right click

Tags: javascript

I have a java script code (my function in below code) which I need to call as soon as user do right click on any area on Php-html page. I tried a lot but it is not working. Javascript function is perfect as it runs in normal scenario but I want to invoke it on right click. So it looks I am missing something.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    <b>MY FUNCTION CONTENT</b>
  }}());
</script>
```

Comment: Your function body is not valid javascript code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first line of [Contextmenu MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/contextmenu)

> The contextmenu event is fired when the right button of the mouse is clicked (before the context menu is displayed)

**Usage Example**:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  alert('Right click');
});
```

Use `e.preventDefault()` inside your handler if you do not wish to show contextMenu to user.